# How to regroup string with same length using awk

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I have a long list of strings like this:

```
_ah_
_asn_
_ai_
_errr_
_an_
```

And I would like to transform it like to this

```
"_ah_ai_an_",
"_asn_",
"_errr_"
```

I have tried :

```
cat file | awk '{ print length, $0 }' | sort -n -s | cut -d" " -f2-
```

Which essentially sort it by length but what I am trying to do is to have those of the same length on the same line with  `","` As delimiters

Comment: How long is that list? Notice that all the answers work by storing the whole file in the memory, which you do NOT want to do with a >> multi GB file. Besides, the challenge would've been much fun if that was a requirement ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the output you want:

```
awk -F_ '
    {strr[length] = strr[length]"_"$2}
    length > max {max=length}
    END {
        for (i=1;i<max;i++) {if (strr[i]) print "\"" strr[i]"_\","}
        print "\"" strr[max]"_\""
    }' file
```

Lines with length `i` are appended to `strr[i]` with a leading `_`. At the end, we just loop through existing `strr` elements and output them with `"<element>_",`, except for the last element, which gets no `,`.

Comment: @EdMorton Of course, you know that you should have written: `awk 'BEGIN{print "\0427\042"}' for the last example.

Comment: This will print a bogus `"_"` line for an empty file. And if you really hate repeating `"\""`, you can set a variable: `awk -v q='"' ...`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you for your suggestion, I updated the answer. It was pointed out to me in the past that the octal quotes was a better idea for the case the awk body would be converted to a script on its own, but of course that is only for `'` and not for `"`.

Comment: Right, that's only for `'` (see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote) and you should always use `\047` for that, not just `\47`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    lgth = length($0)
    sub(/_$/,"",strs[lgth])
    strs[lgth] = strs[lgth] $0
}
END {
    for (lgth in strs) {
        printf "%s\"%s\"", sep, strs[lgth]
        sep = "," ORS
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"_ah_ai_an_",
"_asn_",
"_errr_"
```